# Getting the pixel color from the screen in Cocoa: Swift

Tags: macos, swift, colors, pixel

I have a simple XCode project written in Swift (for Mac) which shows the mouse position on the screen and I'd also like to display the pixel color.

The most important part of my code is if matters:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    var myQueue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue", nil);

    dispatch_async(myQueue, {
        while true {
            self.mouseLoc = NSEvent.mouseLocation()

            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.001)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.xField.floatValue = Float(self.mouseLoc.x)

                self.yField.floatValue = Float(CGDisplayPixelsHigh(CGDirectDisplayID.allZeros)) - Float(self.mouseLoc.y)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

How could I get the pixel color? Please consider that I need to update the color in a tight loop (async).